# Слежение за изменениями в Базе данных VueJS

Tags: javascript, база-данных, веб-программирование, vue.js

Стоит задача: 
При изменении значений в БД на клиенте мгновенно должны произойти изменения.
Какое я вижу решение: посылать ajax-запросы через setTimeout и отображать результат, но мне кажется что это глупо. Есть более приятные решения для VueJS?

Comment: Вам нужен [Websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io)

Comment: А какая реализация на stackoverflow?

Comment: @Илья Османов - рассылка через websocket

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть как минимум 2 решения данной задачи

1. long polling
2. Websockets

Answer (score 1):

Вы собирайетесь "прослушивать" сервер.

"Приятных" решений (кроме уже сказанных) - нет. Посылайте ajax.

**[Вы можете сделать вот так](http://vuejsex)**

setTimeout(app.fetchData, 1000);

```js
  var app =  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created() {
        this.fetchData(); 
    },
    data: {
        posts: []
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response => {
            this.posts = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>//vuejsexamples.net</title>
    <!-- include vue -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <!-- axios -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.15.3/axios.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      Posts:
      <li v-for="post of posts">
        <p><strong>{{post.title}}</strong></p>
        <p>{{post.body}}</p>
      </li>
      
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

amples.net/vuejs-ajax/